# How to tell if a binary sequence is x86 machine code?

Tags: x86, machine-code

We all know that in x86 arch, the data and code is mixed in the memory or disk. But how to tell them?

The method is needed for paper， I wouldn't expect a 100% accuracy. 80%'s just ok, even some ideas would be fine:)

Comment: Have you tried trial decoding yet? Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Trial decoding can have problems if the code is self-mutating. How do you execute commands which are read from memory (which might not be part of the binary sequence)?

Comment: @ronalchn Sure, trial decoding is only step one, but if hsluoyz hasn't even gotten that far we need to know. And we probably start to wonder at his or her commitment to this problem.

Comment: @dmckee, if you mean disassembly by "decoding", I promiss I have got that far. To make it clear, here's an example:

Comment: This is a real x86 code :77834110 >  57              push edi
77834111    8B7C24 0C       mov edi,dword ptr ss:[esp+0xC]
77834115    8B5424 08       mov edx,dword ptr ss:[esp+0x8]
77834119    C702 00000000   mov dword ptr ds:[edx],0x0
7783411F    897A 04         mov dword ptr ds:[edx+0x4],edi
77834122    0BFF            or edi,edi
77834124    74 1E           je Xntdll.77834144
77834126    83C9 FF         or ecx,0xFFFFFFFF
77834129    33C0            xor eax,eax

Comment: 7783412B    F2:AE           repne scas byte ptr es:[edi]
7783412D    F7D1            not ecx
7783412F    81F9 FFFF0000   cmp ecx,0xFFFF
77834135    76 05           jbe Xntdll.7783413C
77834137    B9 FFFF0000     mov ecx,0xFFFF
7783413C    66:894A 02      mov word ptr ds:[edx+0x2],cx
77834140    49              dec ecx
77834141    66:890A         mov word ptr ds:[edx],cx
77834144    5F              pop edi
77834145    C2 0800         retn 0x8

Comment: while this is not:(I just type the keys randomly)      7783465F    55              push ebp
77834660    43              inc ebx
77834661    42              inc edx
77834662    8931            mov dword ptr ds:[ecx],esi
77834664    90              nop
77834665    58              pop eax
77834666    0340 86         add eax,dword ptr ds:[eax-0x7A]
77834669    54              push esp
7783466A    68 806748FE     push 0xFE486780
7783466F    FC              cld

Comment: 77834670    DA58 03         ficomp dword ptr ds:[eax+0x3]
77834673    0A86 3049EFCC   or al,byte ptr ds:[esi+0xCCEF4930]
77834679    70 5D           jo Xntdll.778346D8
7783467B    AD              lods dword ptr ds:[esi]
7783467C    F3:             prefix rep:
7783467D    95              xchg eax,ebp
7783467E    68 386230CD     push 0xCD306238
77834683    DAD8            fcmovu st,st
77834685    035F 90         add ebx,dword ptr ds:[edi-0x70]

Comment: so you can check whether the same registers and/or memory is being accessed multiple times - because useful code always moves data into registers, performs some operation(s), and perhaps moves it back to memory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Statistically determine which commands are common in executables.

Eg. some commands may be add/subtract etc.

For the unknown binary sequence, treat it like machine code, and look at the frequency of the various commands used (here you can probably assume commands start correctly at byte boundaries).

If an invalid command is used, obviously it is not machine code.

Otherwise, see whether the percentage frequency of commands used matches what would be usual.

---

Also, when a command is used which accepts addresses (eg. registers or memory/data locations), record them. Then check if the same locations are being accessed nearby.

This can be done by sorting any data locations used by frequency of usage descending, and seeing of the shape of the decreasing frequency somewhat matches what might be usual.

---

Data (non-machine code) is unlikely to match these statistical tests.

Do note that when I say fit, you can check for very loose fits. Even if it is quite a bit off what is normal, it probably still is code, unless there is almost no correlation statistically.

Comment: In addition, you can analyze jumps to see if they are consistent with your instruction decoding - i.e. that there is no jump into a middle of an instruction.

Comment: And function calls will have one of a small number of templates on each platform in machine generated code. As will many looping constructs.

Comment: @onon15 that can be perfectly valid though. It even occurs in practice (rarely), usually as a branch to the dword in `nop [dword]`.

Comment: @harold that's cool! Didn't know this was done except for manually when trying to fool decompilers.

Comment: @onon15 it's only of limited usefullness, of course. An other variant (which takes less space but can't universally be used) is jumping to the 32bit offset in a `jcc` where the `cc` is guaranteed to be false. I've never heard of compilers using either trick.

Comment: @onon15, In fact the data I try to detect is probably a shellcode, so i'm afraid the jumping into instruction rule isn't fit for this situation? Because a number of shellcodes use this trick for less size.

Comment: @onon15: You can actually re-use the same data with two different entrypoints by employing [skipping instructions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/235553#235553). I use these for code size reasons, not specifically to confuse disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

See [Is all data valid x86 16-bit machine code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16337851/309483).

1. Put your data in a file
2. Run `ndisasm -m 32 > program.dump` (use 16, 32 or 64 when applicable of course)
3. Remove addresses and machine code in hex: `cut -b29- < program.dump > program.dump2`
4. If you used 64-bits above, large instructions will break the line and we'll need to remove those empty lines now: `grep -v '^$' < program.dump2 > program.asm`
5. (The file is now assemble-able)
6. To determine if it consists of only instructions, run `grep -l '^db' < program.asm > /dev/null; echo $?`
7. If you see `0`, it is not all instructions (`grep` found something). If you don't, it is :)