# How do I help GDB disassembler view to synchronize correctly on the instructions?

Tags: gdb, disassembly, machine-code

I am disassembling the memory of the following Python program. The disassembly should start with `int 3` instruction, or `0xcc`, but GDB (running through either clion or qt develop) does not see it and instead shows some kind of `add` instruction that results from decoding one previous byte with it, that is `0x00 0xcc`.

I am aware that x86 assembly is not self-synchronizing ([What happens if `objdump -d --start-address` starts printing from the middle of an x86 instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75262864/what-happens-if-objdump-d-start-address-starts-printing-from-the-middle-of)).

How can I help GDB to synchronize this properly?

[image: qt creator screenshot]

```py
import ctypes
import mmap

buf = mmap.mmap(-1, mmap.PAGESIZE, prot=mmap.PROT_READ | mmap.PROT_WRITE | mmap.PROT_EXEC)
buf.write(
    b'\xcc'  # int 3

    b'\x8b\xc7'  # mov eax, edi
    b'\x83\xc0\x01'  # add eax, 1
    b'\xc3'  # ret
)

f_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int)
f_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(buf)
f = f_type(ctypes.addressof(f_pointer))

result = f(42)
print(f"{result=}")

del f_pointer
buf.close()
```

Comment: Looks like qt develop issues `37-interpreter-exec console "disassemble /rs 0x7ff5ddc4ffed,0x7ff5ddc50065"`. Looks like I can right click, select "Open Disassembler at Address..." and type my own start address. Is there a way to get the IDE figure out the right address automatically? Can I do this in Clion which does not seem to have the Open Disassembler at Address command?

Comment: It is weird that the address for the function is odd; I would have expected it to be 0x7ff5ddc500000 instead — a full page boundary for the mapping.  Can you try maybe doing `buf.tell()` both before & after the `buf.write` and sharing those results?  Also share value of `f_pointer` & `f`.  Also share the return value from `buf.write`.

Comment: The address (of the `int 3` instruction) is `0x7ff5ddc50000`, indeed. it's just that IP has already moved onto the next instruction when the coredump was created (due to SIGTRAP caused by the `int 3`).